# Is there a way of implementing methods for particular casting?

Tags: c#, oop, casting

I have several different classes which represent message data (which implements the `ToString()` method)

- `DatabaseMessage`
- `Method1Message`
- `Method2Message`
- etc...

I then have a `Message` class which has a string which represents the sender and a string which represents one of the about message data classes (from the `ToString()` message). I create this class to send messages down my communication pipe.

At the other end, I create a `Message` class from the string and send it to a particular method which knows exactly which message data type it is. I then want to cast the whole message object to something to be able to get access to the specific message data (eg. `DatabaseMessage` class).

```
class DatabaseMessage
{
    public string ToString()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Message
{
    public string sender;
    public string data;

    public static Message FromString(string message)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

//...

public void Send()
{
    DatabaseMessage db_mess = new DatabaseMessage();

    Message m = new Message();
    m.sender = "me";
    m.data = db_mess.ToString();
}

public void Recieve(string message)
{
    Message m = Message.FromString(message);

    DatabaseMethod(m);
}

public void DatabaseMethod(Message m)
{
    // I want to be able to do this:
    DatabaseMessage db_mess = (DatabaseMessage)m;

    //...
}
```

How would one go about implementing this?

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Are you looking for [object serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx)?

Comment: Maybe the classes `DatabaseMessage`, `Method1Message`, `Method2Message` should all have the class `Message` as their base class? Like so: `class DatabaseMessage : Message { /* ... */ }`

Comment: But how do I handle the casting from a Message with sender & data strings to a DatabaseMessage which has a load of parameters/fields....what is the code to handle this as I need to convert the data string into the DatabaseMessage.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, what you'll want is either an interface, or to extend a particular class.

If you create Message as an interface, you can define that anything which implements it must have particular methods.

Then to get the type you want, you can use something like this:

```
if (myMessage.GetType() == typeof(DatabaseMessage))
{
DatabaseMessage myDatabaseMessage = (DatabaseMessage)myMessage;

//etc...

}
```

But if you've used an interface, you don't even need to care about the type as the methods will work regardless of the object type provided they use the same interface.

Comment: Why do you check the type with `myMessage.GetType() == typeof(DatabaseMessage)` instead of using the `is` or `as` keywords of C#? There's a difference if `myMessage` is of a runtime type _more_ derived than `DatabaseMessage`, for example `SpecialDatabaseMessage` (derives from `DatabaseMessage`).

Comment: Where do I put the code for the casting is what I am asking! Because at some point I need to convert a string to a `DatabaseMessage` object (which I can do - I just don't know where to put the code).

Comment: OK. The expression `myMessage is DatabaseMessage` will return `true` if the runtime type of `myMessage` is either `DatabaseMessage` or something that derives from (or implements in case of `DatabaseMessage` being an interface) `DatabaseMessage`. The `as` is similar, and can be used like so: `var myDatabaseMessage = myMessage as DatabaseMessage; if (myDatabaseMessage != null) { /* your "etc..." */ }`

Comment: But myMessage isn't a `DatabaseMessage` once it has been through the com pipe, its a `Message`...this is the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I won't get into your design, and why do you need to do this.

In order for converting types implicitly or explicitly, you will need to do something that called [Conversion operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx).

By overriding those operators, you can just assign different types of variable, and the appropriate method will be called for conversion. (of course when the conversion types have been supported by the overloaded method that you will implement).

```
    public static explicit operator DatabaseMessage (Message m)  
    {
        DatabaseMessage dm = new ...
        // conversion stuff

        return dm; // return the new DatabaseMessage after conversion
    }
```

Hope this helps.
Ofir.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the typeof class instance would require you to change method code every time a new message type is introduced - violating the [Open/Close Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

I propose another way using serialization of the object instance (XmlSerializer or DatacontractSerializer) as a transport mechanism and then use polymorphism to perform operations on the message.  This way when including a new message type then a new class is introduced and the virtual method overridden, therefor Open Close Principle not violated.

[image]

So on send serialize to Xml, transport and derserialize and then invoke the peformWorkOnMessage() method on the deserialized object..

Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, see what you think of this.

Your problem as stated is that you can't do this:

```
DatabaseMessage db_mess = (DatabaseMessage)m;
```

...because `m` isn't a `DatabaseMessage`, it's a `Message`. As I understand it however, `m.data` is a string which represents a 'serialized' `DatabaseMessage`, so could you continue your `MessageType.FromString()` pattern in your other `Message` types and do this?

```
DatabaseMessage db_mess = DatabaseMessage.FromString(m.data);
```

If the problem is more how to tell what sort of `Message` type is contained in `m.data`, let me know.